# WEB API unit test using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, moq

Trying to add unit test for the below controller.

```
   public HttpResponseMessage pldindexingSummary()
    {
        try
        {       
            Logger.log.Info("Begin GET api/capturestats/pldindexingsummary request from " + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);        
            using (Utilities.CreateTransactionScope())
            {
                if (!PLDGlobals.isPopulated) _repository.PopulatePLDGlobals();
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _repository.GetIndexingSummary());
            }
        }
        catch (EntityException enEx)
        {
            Logger.log.Error("Entity Error in GET api/capturestats/pldindexingsummary", enEx);
            Utilities.SendEmail("GET api/capturestats/pldindexingsummary", Utilities.EntityError + enEx.Message, enEx.StackTrace.ToString(), string.Empty);
            HttpError error = new HttpError(Utilities.EntityError + enEx.Message);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, error);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.log.Error("General Error in GET api/capturestats/pldindexingsummary", ex);
            Utilities.SendEmail("GET api/capturestats/pldindexingsummary", Utilities.ExceptionError + ex.Message, ex.StackTrace.ToString(), string.Empty);
            HttpError error = new HttpError(Utilities.ExceptionError + ex.Message);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, error);
        }
    }

         public static TransactionScope CreateTransactionScope()
    {
        var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions();
        transactionOptions.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted;
        transactionOptions.Timeout = TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout;
        return new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions);
    }
```

This is what i have done so far.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetAllIndexingSummary()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockRepository = new Mock<IPLDRepository>();
        mockRepository.Setup(x => x.GetIndexingSummary())
            .Returns(new List<IndexingSummaryResponseDTO>
        {
            new IndexingSummaryResponseDTO {DocumentQueueId =1, DocumentQueueName = "Sales Upload", DepartmentName = "PLD_SalesUpload", DocumentCount= 10, OldestDocumentDate = "09/01/2016 09:25:50", UserLocation = "Dover" , IsChecked = false, Usernames = "Gupta_A_N0182727, Ansara_E_N0000391, Aronson_D_N0175509" },
            new IndexingSummaryResponseDTO {DocumentQueueId =2, DocumentQueueName = "Inbound Fax Manual", DepartmentName = "PLD_InboundFaxManual", DocumentCount= 20, OldestDocumentDate = "09/02/2016 12:55:04", UserLocation = "Dover" , IsChecked = false, Usernames = "Bent_E_N0156485, Herron_E_N0175690" },
            new IndexingSummaryResponseDTO {DocumentQueueId =3, DocumentQueueName = "Rating Scan", DepartmentName = "PLD_RatingScan", DocumentCount= 30, OldestDocumentDate = "09/03/2016 04:45:08", UserLocation = "Dover" , IsChecked = false, Usernames = "Gupta_A_N0182727, Jinkens_M_N0178324" },
            new IndexingSummaryResponseDTO {DocumentQueueId =4, DocumentQueueName = "Indexing/Loading Error", DepartmentName = "PLD_IndexingLoadingError", DocumentCount= 50, OldestDocumentDate = "09/04/2016 05:10:28", UserLocation = "Dover" , IsChecked = false, Usernames = "Gupta_A_N0182727, Keshavarz_M_N0070514" },
            new IndexingSummaryResponseDTO {DocumentQueueId =5, DocumentQueueName = "Prod Center Scan", DepartmentName = "PLD_ProdCenterScan", DocumentCount= 60, OldestDocumentDate = "09/05/2016 16:12:12", UserLocation = "Dover" , IsChecked = false, Usernames = "Libby_S_N0145549, Long_S_N0236534, Miller_K_N0177119" },
            new IndexingSummaryResponseDTO {DocumentQueueId =6, DocumentQueueName = "Prod Center Inbound Fax", DepartmentName = "PLD_ProdCenterInboundFax", DocumentCount= 70, OldestDocumentDate = "09/06/2016 15:25:03", UserLocation = "Dover" , IsChecked = false, Usernames = "Parmer_N_N0290328, Porter_S_N0074020" },
            new IndexingSummaryResponseDTO {DocumentQueueId =7, DocumentQueueName = "Research Dover", DepartmentName = "PLD_ResearchDover", DocumentCount= 0, OldestDocumentDate = "N/A", UserLocation = "Dover" , IsChecked = false, Usernames = "Porter_S_N0074020" },
            new IndexingSummaryResponseDTO {DocumentQueueId =8, DocumentQueueName = "Orlando Fax/Scan", DepartmentName = "PLD_OrlandoFaxScan", DocumentCount= 80, OldestDocumentDate = "09/08/2016 21:25:03", UserLocation = "Orlando" , IsChecked = false, Usernames = "Putnam_S_N0199165" },
            new IndexingSummaryResponseDTO {DocumentQueueId =9, DocumentQueueName = "Research Orlando Fax/Scan", DepartmentName = "PLD_ResearchOrlandoFaxScan ", DocumentCount= 10, OldestDocumentDate = "09/09/2016 18:25:03", UserLocation = "Orlando" , IsChecked = false, Usernames = "Seefeld_J_N0030634" },
        });

        var controller = new CaptureStatsController(mockRepository.Object);
        controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();

        //Act
        var result = controller.pldindexingSummary();         

        Assert.IsNotNull(result, "Result is null");

        IList<IndexingSummaryResponseDTO> product;
            Assert.IsTrue(result.TryGetContentValue<IList<IndexingSummaryResponseDTO>>(out product));
         Assert.AreEqual(10, product.Count);
    }
```

I am getting NullReference Exception : Object reference not set to an instance of object. 
This is my first Unit test.I am not sure where it is going wrong. I have followed the Microsoft article. reference link : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api

Comment: Where are you getting the error. you need to narrow down exactly where the error is occurring. Debug and step through your code.

Comment: what is inside `Utilities.CreateTransactionScope()`?

Comment: @Nkosi : I am not sure how to debug unit test..this is my 1st test case..

Comment: @NiravParmar add the code above to the original question. Don't use comments for code snippets.

Comment: @NiravParmar put a break point in the test. next find the test in the test runner and select debug selected test. it should start the debugger and stop at the break point. form there step through the code with F10 or F11.

Comment: I updated the transactionScope in Question..Ok got it..it is getting error at line var result = controller.pldindexingSummary();

Comment: Step into the action (F11) and continue debugging to narrow down exactly where the error is.

Comment: @Nkosi : you are awesome!!! got the error..there is this line of code Logger.log.Info where it was giving error. I commented it and its working fine but how can i still keep it and have my test running..It using Log4net..Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @NiravParmar, so, you have identified the problem now you need to find a way to mock the logger dependency so that you can run your test.

Comment: @NiravParmar, `HttpContext.Current` this is also going to be a problem. It is not very unit test friendly. read up on SOLID principles and refactor your code to make it easier to test and maintain.

Comment: @Nkosi : Thank you for your valuable feedback..I learned something new from you. I will definitely make those changes..